# How to migrate data from a CDH3 cluster to a (different) CDH4 cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I want to copy data from CDH3 to CDH4 (on a different server). My CDH4 server is set up such that it cannot see the CDH3, so I have to push data upstream from CDH3 to CDH4. (which means I cannot run the distcp command from CDH4 to copy the data). How can I get my data over to CDH4' HDFS via running a command on the lower version CDH3 hadoop or is this not possible?

Comment: Do you mean copying data from one HDFS cluster to another HDFS cluster ? What's the exact version number of your CDH3 and CDH4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use distcp with the following command when transferring b/w 2 different versions of HDFS (Notice **hftp**):

hadoop distcp **hftp**://Source-namenode:50070/user/ hdfs://destination-namenode:8020/user/

Comment: This does not work if executed on the CDH3 machine, it only works if ran on CDH4 machine. I want to execute something from the CDH3 machine to get data over to the CDH4 machine.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should be able to use distcp to copy the data from one HDFS cluster to another.

```
hadoop distcp -p -update "hdfs://A:8020/user/foo/bar" "hdfs://B:8020/user/foo/baz"
```

-p to preserve status, -update to overwrite data if a file is already present but has a different size.

In practice, depending on the exact versions of Cloudera you're using, you may run into incompatibilities issues such as [CRC mismatch errors](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8060). In this case, you can try to use [HTFP](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/08/httpfs-for-cdh3-the-hadoop-filesystem-over-http/) instead of HDFS, or upgrade your cluster to the latest version of CDH4 and check the [release notes](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Release-Notes/CDH4-Release-Notes.html) to see if there is any relevant known issue and work-around.

If you still have issues using distcp, feel free to create a new stackoverflow question with the exact error message, versions of CDH3 and CDH4, and exact command.

Answer (score 0):

DistCp is intra-cluster only.

The only way I know is "fs -get", "fs -put" for every subset of data that can fit local disc.

Comment: What do you mean by "DistCp is intra-cluster only" ?

Answer (score 0):

For copying between two different versions of Hadoop, one will usually use HftpFileSystem. This is a read-only FileSystem, so DistCp must be run on the destination cluster (more specifically, on TaskTrackers that can write to the destination cluster). Each source is specified as hftp:/// (the default dfs.http.address is :50070).